# How can I use FsCheck with a portable class library?

Tags: f#, portable-class-library, fscheck

How can I use FsCheck with a portable class library?

I receive the following error:

> Error     Could not install package 'FsCheck.Xunit 2.5.0'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not
>   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
>   with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Does this mean FsCheck is not PCL compliant?

Comment: Why do you want your tests to be PCL-compliant? Surely you're not distributing your tests as a production library?